# Led Matrix on the PI

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi4, neopixel

I'm working a little project using a neopixel *like* matrix board. The board in question is [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08T61FQKD). Now this is my first adventure into addressable led boards. And I was extremely frustrated to learn that the board came with zero documentation nor was there really anything about it on the internet. I did eventually find some docs on the LEDs on the board.

They are the WS2812b, The docs are [here](https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/2371852/0/0/1/ws2812b-led.html?utm_adgroup=General&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search_EN_RLSA_Cart&utm_term=&utm_content=General&gclid=Cj0KCQiAzMGNBhCyARIsANpUkzNPHE5cGEwWzz6zzQQzAXxRXDtBc0jxdEkotqVtOtnI2Oq6vow-T9QaAgyNEALw_wcB). So I've written some code based on my perception of how it works. The docs arent really the best. So I'm sure i'm misunderstanding it.

Heres the code for it.

```
using namespace std;
#define DATA 23


void send1()
{
    //T1H
    digitalWrite(DATA, HIGH);
    usleep(0.85);
    //T1L
    digitalWrite(DATA, LOW);
    usleep(0.4);
}

void send0()
{
    //T0H
    digitalWrite(DATA, HIGH);
    usleep(0.4);
    //T1L
    digitalWrite(DATA, LOW);
    usleep(0.85);
}

void sendReset()
{

    //Treset
    digitalWrite(DATA, LOW);
    usleep(55);
}


int main(void)
{
    wiringPiSetupSys();
    while (true)
    {
        //256 pixels total
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            //3 bytes GRB
            for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
                //G set to 0
                for (int g = 0; g < 8; g++) {
                    send0();
                }
                //R set to 255
                for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) {
                    send1();
                }
                //B set to 0
                for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
                    send0();
                }
            }
            //reset after bytes sent
            sendReset();
        }

            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Heres the result

[image]

As you can see it doesn't work at all!

Using that code I ran a scope on my gpio pin and this is what that looks like.

[image]

I've been working on this for a few hours and the most I've been able to do is turn on all the LEDs to white. And I did that with this code

```
    while (true) {
        digitalWrite(DATA, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(DATA, LOW);
    }
```

This does reliably turn everything white at least.

[image]

Comment: The hint I find on the amazon page is `"download the Adafruit_NeoPixel library from GITHUB"` -- which is where I would start by looking at the code. Since the panel is 8x32 I would suspect you should be able to supply some type of 256-byte buffer to the controller where each 8-bit value will be used to control an LED (my guess). Take a look at the code, or search for the data-sheet for the controller model.

Comment: I saw that comment. They dont support the pi. But from my scope it appears that the pi should be capable of doing this. So I'm working on it.

Comment: I do work with the TI boards. Much of the Arduino and Pi code is written in C. They are usually decently commented. I've found you can get a good idea of how something unfamiliar works that way. Good luck.